# Update ListView Widget with Application

Tags: android, listview, widget, android-widget

I have a problem with my App Widget when i try to update the content from my application. My widget contains a listview.

The listview works fine and it updates every 30 minutes, but I also need to update it when i make changes in the application. Here is my code:

```
public class WidgetListProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        ComponentName component;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                    appWidgetIds[i]);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);

            component=new ComponentName(context,WidgetListProvider.class);
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.listViewWidget);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(component, remoteViews);
        }

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_list_layout);

        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.listViewWidget, svcIntent);
        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);
        return remoteViews;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() after the list is updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put this code in your application where you are updating content.

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
int appWidgetIds[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetListProvider.class));
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.listViewWidget);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I also need to update it when i make changes in the application

You can get an `AppWidgetManager` whenever you need to, via the static `getInstance()` method. So long as you keep track of which app widget ID you need to update, you can largely go through your existing code when other work in your app requires your app widget contents to update.